# List of html attributes that could be displayed to user in some cases in browser

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am designing a web scraping script using Python. I am using the beautifulsoup module for this and I almost succeeded in this. Currently, I am having some requirements unsatisfied in beautifulsoup.
When extracting the content that could be displayed to the user in a browser using beautifulsoup, it's not displaying some text like the "placeholder" attribute value of an input tag element. I wrote the below code for a demonstration of this behavior.

Python code:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs4

web_page = requests.get("http://localhost/1.html", allow_redirects=True)

web_view = bs4(web_page.text, "html.parser")

print(web_view.text)
```

HTML code of http://localhost/1.html is

```html
<html>
<title>Test Website</title>
<body>
<p>Hello World</p>
<form>
<input placeholder="Username"/>
<input placeholder="Password" type="password"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The output of above said Python code is:

```
Test Website

Hello World
```

I am expecting the "Username" word, and "Password" word also extracted in the python output because that is also displayed to the user in the browser.
My requirement is not limited to the "placeholder" attribute of the "input" element tag. I need to display the text that could be displayed to the user in the browser when some exception happens. For example, if an image is missing that is placed in an "img" tag of any html page of any website, the user will see the text that is provided in the "alt" attribute of the "img" tag like this.

[image: Browser output]

HTTML code for this page:

```html
<html>
<title>Test Website</title>
<body>
<p>Hello World</p>
<form>
<input placeholder="Username"/>
<input placeholder="Password" type="password"/>
<br><br><br>
<img source="2.img" alt="Image missing">
</body>
</html>
```

"2.img" is the image, and it is missing I know.

My overall question is:

I need to see all those web page content that is displayed to the user in the browser including any exception cases like the image missing. Currently, beautifulsoup is displaying only the "value" of any dom element tag and it's not extracting any text that is part of any attributes of the dom element tag that could be displayed to the user. I need that attributes' value also.

If this information can be extracted from beautifullsoup, I am happy to see how to do it. But if it's not possible, I would like to know all the html tag attributes (as a list) that are coming under this category so that I can write a code to search those html attributes through all the html tags on an html page.

If complete list of attributes is not possible, I am requesting everyone to provide the attribute names of any tags you know that are coming under above said use case so that I can prepare a list that may be partially correct.

Edited:

In short:

What are all the attributes' value of any html tag that might be displayed to user in browser. You know and I know, "placeholder" attribute value (of input tag) will be displayed to user in browser. "alt" attribute value of image tag will be displayed to user if image is missing. Like placeholder, and alt attributes, what are all the other attributes out there?

Comment: when you accessed the text in `web_view.text` you only get the text content of the entire page, you are not printing the entire html content.

Comment: I am aware of it. My requirement is different.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding to your first question, you can't expect `.text` attribute to give you attributes of specific tags. You need to use `.attrs['<attr_name>']`[[docs]](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#attributes) to get desired output:

```
input_tags = web_view.find('form').find_all('input')
placeholders = [each.attrs['placeholder'] for each in input_tags]
# -> ['Username', 'Password']
```

As for the second question, you can find all `img` tags and print its `alt` attribute if that's what you are looking for:

```
imgs = web_view.find_all('img')
alt_attrs = [each.attrs['alt'] for each in imgs]
# -> ['Image missing']
```

---

To get each attribute of certain tag you need to call `.attrs`:

```
input_tags = web_view.find('form').find_all('input')
attributes = [each.attrs for each in input_tags]
# -> [{'placeholder': 'Username'}, {'placeholder': 'Password', 'type': 'password'}]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I don't need html content of any web page. I need how it's going to displayed to user in browser. beautifulsoup is providing it partially if you read my original question carefully.

Comment: I edited my question. The "Edited" section is containing my question in short form.

Comment: I am aware of how to get a attribute value out of any html tag. The thing I am not aware of is, the name of the attribute of any html tag that might be displayed to user in browser. For an example, "placeholder" attribute value (of input tag) will be displayed to user. But "type" attribute value (of input tag) will not be displayed (because type is a functionality attribute) to user in browser. Right? . So I want to know all those "placeholder", and "alt" KIND OF attributes' names (very very simple form of my question).

Comment: @SanthoshKumar, if you want to see all attributes of certain tag, you can just use `.attrs`, which will return attributes in a dictionary with each attribute name being key and its value being key value. Edited answer

Comment: Thank You! But Sorry that doesn't answer my question.